# Android - inflater menu disable / enable

Tags: java, android

I had an inflater menu created in a fragment.
This is the code.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

It works, but I want that if I click on a button the inflater is disable. It means that also if I click on the inflater it doesn't show the menu. When I click on another button the inflater return to show its options. How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot enable or disable an inflater. What you can do is enable/disable or hide/show the menu items that it created.

Comment: take a look at [Changing menu items at runtime](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu)